# Rails model JSON not showing associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following models:

```
class Office < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :city
  belongs_to :company
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :acquirer
  has_many :offices 
  has_many :cities, through: :offices
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :offices
end
```

My Offices controller is set up this way:

```
class OfficesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_office, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  respond_to :html, :json
  def index
    respond_with(@offices = Office.all(:include => [:company, :city]))
  end
  ...
```

And my schema.rb:

```
  create_table "cities", id: false, force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name",       null: false
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "companies", id: false, force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name",        null: false
    t.string   "website"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "acquirer_id"
  end

  create_table "offices", force: true do |t|
    t.boolean  "headquarters"
    t.string   "city_id"
    t.string   "company_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

I'm not really sure what's wrong.

All I really want is to show the company_id and city_id columns. I have an Acquisitions Controller that shows these columns in JSON even without the respond_with method. So I don't understand why it works by default in that case and not in this. I'm using Rails 4.0.0 with Ruby 2.0.0.

Comment: It is probably not related to your problem, but is it intentionnal to have `company_id` and `city_id` defined by string type?

Comment: yes. is that good practice?

Comment: By default ActiveRecord define primary key as an Integer. So if you do not change type of primary key, you should refers to it by Integer column instead of String

Comment: yep I did change the primary key to a string using `execute "ALTER TABLE companies ADD PRIMARY KEY (name);"` on db migration.

Comment: I should learn to read, my mistake. I don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

You should always use integer for defining foreign keys.
Coming back to your question, you can use

```
respond_with Office.all(:include => [:company, :city])).as_json(:include => [:company,:city])
```

However, if you have complex JSON responses I would suggest you to look at [RABL](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) or [jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder)

Comment: hmm that did not work. I'm getting a [] in my json file. I did realize I have the jbuilder gem that comes with Rails 4, hence changing the jbuilder file did get me the results.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. Leaving controller as it is, I changed index.json.jbuilder from:

```
json.array!(@offices) do |office|
  json.extract! office, :headquarters
  json.url office_url(office, format: :json)
end
```

to:

```
json.array!(@offices) do |office|
  json.extract! office, :headquarters, :company_id, :city_id
  json.url office_url(office, format: :json)
end
```

Not sure what you guys think of this fix?